# Rails: Minitest tests fail when they should pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd, railstutorial.org, minitest

Following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, I am testing for the `<title>` of my static pages with Minitest in Rails.

Here is the `static_pages_controller_test.rb` file:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | Microblog"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get :help
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | Microblog"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Microblog"
  end

end
```

Here is the Home page `home.html.erb` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home | Microblog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Microblog</h1>
    <p>
        This is the homepage for Microblog, a brand new microblogging app.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

`help.html.erb` and `about.html.erb` basically contain the same content, with slight variations.

So, from my understanding, tests should pass.

However, when I run `rake`, I get:

```
Run options: --seed 47355

# Running:

FFF

Finished in 0.112314s, 26.7109 runs/s, 53.4217 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home [/Users/TXC/code/microblog/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:7]:
<Home | Microblog> expected but was
<Home | Microblog>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.


  2) Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help [/Users/TXC/code/microblog/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:13]:
<Help | Microblog> expected but was
<Help | Microblog>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.


  3) Failure:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about [/Users/TXC/code/microblog/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:19]:
<About | Microblog> expected but was
<About | Microblog>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.

3 runs, 6 assertions, 3 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

In particular, I don't understand why I get:

```
<Home | Microblog> expected but was
    <Home | Microblog>..
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**: I went on with the tutorial and followed the guidelines in the *Advanced testing setup* section.

Here is what I get when I run all the tests with Guard:

```
[1] guard(main)> 
11:41:17 - INFO - Run all
11:41:17 - INFO - Running: all tests
Started

 FAIL["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2015-06-20 19:36:39 -0700]
 test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (1434854199.36s)
        <Home | Microblog> expected but was
        <Home | Microblog>..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

 FAIL["test_should_get_help", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2015-06-20 19:36:39 -0700]
 test_should_get_help#StaticPagesControllerTest (1434854199.37s)
        <Help | Microblog> expected but was
        <Help | Microblog>..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

 FAIL["test_should_get_about", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2015-06-20 19:36:39 -0700]
 test_should_get_about#StaticPagesControllerTest (1434854199.38s)
        <About | Microblog> expected but was
        <About | Microblog>..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:19:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

  3/3: [===================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.22498s
3 tests, 6 assertions, 3 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I kept investigating the causes of the problem but did not find anything conclusive so far.

Any idea?

Comment: Really I don't known, but have you try to replace pipe character ? or escape it ?

Comment: @fellons That's a good remark, I had not thought about it. But I just took a look at the files, and it happens that the pipe character is not in the <%= ... %> tags. I replaced it anyway with a dash character but got the same test results. I also escaped it, but the test still did not pass. Really weird. This may be due to a version of the gems I use.

Comment: maybe here you can find howto debug whats happen. https://coderwall.com/p/bbxb8g/use-ruby-debugger-when-debugging-rspecs

Comment: Thanks for the link @fellons I am afraid this is beyond my skills but I will give it a try and get back here if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I kept following the tutorial, and in the next chapter (Chapter 4), at some point, we create the `full_title` helper and remove the <% provide(:title, "Home") %> from the views.

I am not sure how, but this solved the problem and made the tests to pass:

```
11:49:36 - INFO - Running: test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb
Started

 FAIL["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2015-06-20 19:36:39 -0700]
 test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (1434854199.39s)
        <Microblog> expected but was
        <Home | Microblog>..
        Expected 0 to be >= 1.
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

  3/3: [===================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.21526s
3 tests, 6 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips


11:50:15 - INFO - Running: test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb
Started

  3/3: [===================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.21126s
3 tests, 6 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Hope that helps if you stumble upon the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your comment about the pipe character, not being between <%=  %>. Because: your files are not testing the ''yielded' titles with the erb . That happens later in the tutorial.
In this test, you should test the 'simple' html format. 
Any chance this is the problem?

I don't remember exactly what this test was about, but could it be something with your routing?

Comment: This test is only about checking whether we have <title> tags in the home, about and help pages, and whether these <title> tags respectively contain the "Home | Microblog", "About | Microblog" and "Help | Microblog". Microblog being the name of the app. In the tutorial, instead of "Home | Microblog", we are testing "Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" etc. I did implement the necessary changes to test the right text.

Comment: My comment about the pipe character was based on the following reasoning: in the app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb file, we have <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Microblog</title> and not <title><%= yield(:title) | Microblog%></title> so I was confused about escaping a pipe from simple HTML code. Anyway, I tried and did not fix the problem. Does it make more sense?